# AngularJS DOM traversal Concept

Tags: angularjs

Can i traverse the DOM in angular like jquery ? In jquery there are multiple functions like parent(),siblings(), find(), children() etc... like this, Is there any functions in angularjs?

Is there any 'this' keyword in angular DOM traverse like jquery where in jquery this means the current element ?

Any reference links will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular comes with a cut down bundled version of jQuery, called jQuery lite:

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

In the main, full blown Jquery and Angular can live together, however it is recommended not to use them at the same time - there is generally a much better angular way of achieving what you need to do. For instance testing your logic will be easier.

"This" in your example would refer to something off the current controller and on that controller's scope. It is recommended that you use angular to control and manipulate that element in angular.